# How can i store data from a form in the safest way possible in Django?

Tags: python, django, security, django-forms, django-views

I'm creating a site in django; at a certain point, i should be able to store an API key. Obviosuly, this API key should not be stolen, so i need to store it in the safest way possible, just like Django does with passwords.

My question is: is there a way to encrypt data submitted from a form in django? I know how to send data from a form, but how can i store it in the safest way possible?

Comment: I'm no security expert, but passwords are usually stored after going through a secure hash function, I don't see why you couldn't do the same with an API key or anything else that's too sensitive to store in plaintext.

Comment: check methods for storing passwords

Answer (score 1):

Use a

> csrf_token

As this adds an extra layer of security also try using third-party Django libraries,
If You are using Authentication System to sign in using the build in Django systems, they have good security.